# How to convert the stacklayout content to stream in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, stream, pdf-viewer

I have added some controls inside stacklayout in xamarin forms. I want to get the stream of the page. So I can use the stream to view it in PDF viewer.

Comment: "get the stream of the page" - this is nonsensical.  If you want to create a PDF representation of your page this is not how to do it.

Comment: This will let you take the screenshot of your current screen : https://xamarinhelp.com/taking-a-screenshot-in-xamarin-forms/
You can make the pdf out of those pictures!